# Lifecycle methods in statically typed languages

Tags: android, ios, swift, functional-programming, kotlin

In the last year I've become a mobile developer and a functional programming admirer.

In each of the mobile arenas there are components with lifecycle methods that make up the meat of the app. The following will use Android and Kotlin as examples, but the same applies to iOS and Swift.

In Android, there are `Activity`'s with lifecycle methods like `onCreate()`. You might also define a function, `onButtonClicked()`, which will do exactly what the name describes.

For the purposes of the question, let's say there's a variable defined in `onCreate()` that is used in a button click handler `onButtonClickedPrintMessageLength()` (*This is usually the case - `onCreate()` is essentially `Activity`'s setup method*).

The example class would look like this:

```
class ExampleActivity: Activity() {
    var savedStateMessage: String? = null
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        savedStateMessage = "Hello World!"
    }

    fun onButtonClickedPrintMessageLength() {
        System.out.println(savedStateMessage?.length)
    }
}
```

Notice the declaration of `savedStateMessage` as a `String?` (nullable string) and the use of `?.` (null safe call). These are required because the compiler cant guarantee that `onCreate()` will be called before `onButtonClickedPrintMessageLength()`. As developers though, [we know that `onCreate` will always be called first](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle)***** ******.

My question is **how can I tell the compiler about the guaranteed order of these methods and eliminate the null checking behavior?**

* I suppose it's possible to `new` up our `ExampleActivity` and call `onButtonClickedPrintMessageLength()` directly, thus sidestepping the Android framework and lifecycle methods, but the compiler/JVM would likely run into an error before anything interesting happened.

** The guarantee that `onCreate` is called first is provided by the Android framework, which is an external source of truth and might break/function differently in the future. Seeing that all Android apps are based on this source of truth though, I believe it's safe to trust.

Comment: You can't tell the compiler the order of methods, but you can (in your case) enforce the type to `String` and provide an unuseful default value : `var savedStateMessage: String = "default stupid value"`.

Comment: You should probably split this question into separate questions for each relevant programming language/environment. If you don't then you run into the problem that several answers may be correct even though only one can be accepted.

Comment: I agree with you, ColGraff. I should have separated this question into two: one for Android and one for iOS. Next time I'll ask only one, or create both questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although this won't answer your actual question, in Kotlin you can use `lateinit` to tell the compiler that you'll initialize a `var` at a later point in time:

`lateinit var savedStateMessage: String`

You'll get a very specific `UninitializedPropertyAccessException` if you try to use this variable before initializing it. This feature is useful in use cases like JUnit, where you'd usually initialize variables in `@Before`-annotated method, and Android `Activity`s, where you don't have access to the constructor and initialize stuff in `onCreate()`.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in another answer, [`lateinit`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#late-initialized-properties) is available as an option to defer initialization to a later point in a *guaranteed lifecycle*.  An alternative is to use a delegate:

```
var savedStateMessage: String by Delegates.notNull()
```

Which is equivalent, in that it will report an error if you access the variable before initializing it.

Answer (score 0):

In Swift this is where you would use an implicitly-unwrapped `Optional`:

```
class Example: CustomStringConvertible {
  var savedStateMessage: String! // implicitly-unwrapped Optional<String>
  var description: String { return savedStateMessage }
  init() {
    savedStateMessage = "Hello World!"
  }
}

print(Example()) // => "Hello World!\n"
```

By using the operator `!` at the end of `String` in the second line of the example you are promising that the variable will be set before it can be used. This is accomplished in the `init` method of the example. It's still an `Optional` but code can treat it as a `String` since it will be automatically unwrapped before each use. You must take care that the variable is never set to `nil` when it might be accessed or a runtime exception may be generated.

Comment: Does the compiler produce any warnings if somewhere I accidentally write `myCustomStringConvertable.description = null`? Ideally the compiler would yell at me when *I* set the variable to null, but will not yell at me when the compiler cant verify whether or not it's been initialized.